# Semantic Issue when building a XCode5 project in XCode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, xcode6

I have an App ready for distribution (started in Xcode 5.1.1 as an Utility App and fully developed and tested in XCode5) and after Xcode 6 download I just tried to build it in Xcode6 just for curiosity and to be sure there are no bugs.

However I am getting the following issue on the "self" of the last line of the standard prepareForSegue to the FlipSideViewController in the MainViewController:

Issue: Sending 'MainViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

I have read in other posts that when this happened in the past, it can be disregarded but I do not like to keep this issue if I decide to go with Xcode 6. Is there any way to easily tell the compiler something in order to have again the No Issue I have in XCode5?

Comment: "building a XCode5 in XCode6" WAT?

Comment: Most likely your class doesn't declare that it conforms to the delegate protocol.

Comment: probably I was not clear enough. It is nothing related to my class. That's a standard Utility App, created with XCode5. If you open it with XCode6 without doing any change or adding anything, you get that issue. Any help please?

Comment: @LeoNatan = ...(started in Xcode 5.1.1 as an Utility App and fully developed and tested in XCode5) and after Xcode 6 download I just tried to build it in Xcode6...

Comment: So please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: @LeoNatan Sorry, I think I missed a word. Could you be so kind, in case you are able to help, to give me an advice in order to fix this issue please? Tnxs

Comment: How is the delegate property defined?

Comment: @LeoNatan Thanks. The best way for you to have a look at it, if you have Xcode 5.1.1, is this: just create a App Utility project without any modifications. cmd-R and it will work. Save it and open it with Xcode 6. Cmd-R: you'll get the issue I am talking about. Tnxs